# JQGrid addRowData rowId always zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am working with **jqGrid  4.4.4V**, I have two grids let say grid1 and grid2, 
when i add multiple Rows to grid2 from grid1 the row id's are updating like 0,1,...But when i am adding single row each the id is starting from '0'.So, if i do multiple times like this, all rowIds will be like '0' only. Is there any way to make rowIds as always unique.

Note: the data is not adding manually to the grid, is getting from a sql. Below are the code for two grids.

**grid1:**

```js
 $("#grid1").jqGrid({
            url: "/.......some handler path",
            datatype: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
            mtype: 'Get',
            colNames: ['Val ID', 'Val Name', 'Description', 'Dept', 'Vam', 'Venue', 'Venue', 'Solution', 'Method', 'Type'],
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'valId', index: 'valId', hidden: true },
                    { name: 'valName', index: 'valName', formatter: Namefield, width: 400 },
                    { name: 'description', index: 'description', width: 300 },
                    { name: 'dep', index: 'dep', width: 300 },
                    { name: 'vam', index: 'vam', width: 300 },
                    { name: 'venueId', index: 'venueId', hidden: true },
                    { name: 'venue', index: 'venue', width: 250 },
                    { name: 'solution', index: 'solution', width: 400 },
                    { name: 'Method', index: 'Method', width: 300 },
                    { name: 'Type', index: 'Type', hidden: true },
            ],
            pager: $('#pager'),
            key:true,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
            height: '100%',
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: '',
            sortname: 'Val Name',
            sortorder: "desc",
            emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
            autowidth: true,
            multiselect: true,
            multiselectWidth: 50,
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                Id: "0"
            }
   });
```

**grid2:**

```js
 $("#grid2").jqGrid({
                datatype: 'function',
                mtype: 'Post',
                colNames: ['Val ID', 'Val Name', 'Description', 'Dept', 'Vam', 'Venue ID', 'Venue', 'Solution', 'Method', 'Type'],
                colModel: [
                        { name: 'valId', index: 'valId', hidden: true },
                        { name: 'valName', index: 'valName', formatter: Namefield, width: 400 },
                        { name: 'description', index: 'description', width: 300 },
                        { name: 'dep', index: 'dep', width: 300 },
                        { name: 'vam', index: 'vam', width: 300 },
                        { name: 'venueId', index: 'venueId', hidden: true },
                        { name: 'venue', index: 'venue', width: 250 },
                        { name: 'solution', index: 'solution', width: 400 },
                        { name: 'Method', index: 'Method', width: 300 },
                        { name: 'Type', index: 'Type', hidden: true },
{ name: 'delete', index: 'delete', width: 50, formatter: Close, align: 'center' }
                ],
                pager: $('#pager'),
                key:true,
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
                height: '100%',
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: '',
                sortname: 'Val Name',
                sortorder: "desc",
                emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
                autowidth: true,
                multiselect: true,
                multiselectWidth: 50,
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "rows",
                    page: "page",
                    total: "total",
                    records: "records",
                    repeatitems: false,
                    Id: "0"
                }
       });
```

Where I am using the add and del methods as below,

```js
        var selRowIdsArray = [];
        var myGrid = $("#grid1");
        var SelectedGrid = $('#grid2');
        //get no of selected rows count
        var selRowIds = $("#grid1").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
        if (selRowIds.length !== 0) {
            if (selRowIdsArray.length == 0) {
                selRowIdsArray.push.apply(selRowIdsArray, selRowIds);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < selRowIdsArray.length; i++) {
                selRowIdsInt = selRowIdsArray[i];
                var selRowId = myGrid.getRowData(selRowIdsInt);
                SelectedGrid.jqGrid('addRowData', i, selRowId);
                myGrid.jqGrid('delRowData', selRowIdsInt);
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of you problem could be very easy if you good understand what is rowid and what do `idPrefix` option of jqGrid. It's the value of `id` attribute of `<tr>` elements of the corresponding HTML `<table>`, which displays the data. The internal implementation of jqGrid is so, that jqGrid **must** assign `id` to every row of the grid, which corresponds the data. It's strictly recommended to include an unique `id` property in every item. It could be native id from the database or some composite key like `id1 + "_" + id2`, which hold full information about the native ids from the backend. I recommend you to examine [the picture](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div) from [the article](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#the_first_grid).

You can place the id under any other name as `id`. If you use `repeatitems: false` option of `jsonReader`, and `valId` is the name of the unique id, then you  should use

```
jsonReader: { id: "valId" }
```

to inform jqGrid about that. Including of any other properties of `jsonReader` with *default* values, like you did, is unneeded. Any other properties of `jsonReader`, like `Id` (instead of `id`), will be just ignored. After that you can **remove unneeded hidden column `valId`** from the grid, which saves the same information in `<td>` elements of the grid.

I recommend to add one more option, if you use editing of the grid

```
prmNames: { id: "valId" }
```

The option renames the `id` property, send on editing of the grid, to `valId`. Thus you can just continue to use `valId` instead of `id`.

Next you should understand that rowid can be not the same as id (`valId`). If you  have more as one grid on the page then it will be strictly recommended to use `idPrefix`. It's supported even on the retro version 4.4.4 of jqGrid (4 years old version), which you use. For example, you can use `idPrefix: "g1_"` in the first grid and `idPrefix: "g2_"` in the second grid. It **prevents id dupplicates** on HTML page, because the rowid will be build from id (`valId`) with the corresponding id prefix, different for both grids.

After understanding the meaning of rowid, it should be clear how one can move selected rows from one grid to another. The statement

```
var selRowIds = $("#grid1").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
var idPrefix1 = $("#grid1").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'idPrefix');
```

gives you the rowids (with the `idPrefix` of the first grid) of selected rows and the prefix `idPrefix1`, which you use. You can use `$.jgrid.stripPref` to strip the prefix, `getRowData` to get the row data and to use `addRowData` to add the same data to the second grid, using the same id

```
var i, id, item;
for (i = 0; i < selRowIds.length; i++) {
    id = $.jgrid.stripPref(idPrefix1, selRowIds[i]);
    item = myGrid.jqGrid("getRowData", id);
    SelectedGrid.jqGrid("addRowData", id, item);
}
```

`addRowData` will automatically use `idPrefix` of the second grid.

Finally, I'd recommend you to drop using of retro version 4.4.4 which is **dead** since many years. I'd suggest you to use the current version (4.13.6) of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) - it's the fork of jqGrid, which I develop starting with the end of 2014. If you installed 4.4.4 because of usage of wrong NuGet package [jQuery.jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.jqGrid/), then you should uninstall the package and install another one: [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/).

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation, have got some knowledge through it. But i am getting an error:**"Cannot read property '0' of undefined"** in min.js file, have thoroughly checked but did not find the reason, thinking this might cause with unsupporting issue, grid has loaded with headers but stopped displaying as "Loading"

Comment: @Virat: **Which code you use currently?** You should never use `.min.js` if you get any errors. The `.src.js` could show you the exact line of the source code where you get the error `read property '0' of undefined`. Which version of jqGrid you use now (still 4.4.4 or some other one)? Do you have the demo online, which reproduces the problem and which I could debug?